# Google Maps v3 API - hitting geocoding limits

Tags: google-maps

We have 2 websites hosted on a Cloud Server.  Our provider has assured us that we have our own IP for the server.

- The first does an address lookup.
- The other is a store finder function to find local your lawyer.

Every few days we get the message.

*You are over your query limit for the Google's Geocoding services. If you are on a shared IP, it's advised you upgrade to a dedicated IP so you dont have to share your requests with other sites. For more information on Geocoding limits, go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits*

The api stops working [I assume blocked by Google].

Some notes:

- We have check the api log on Google and only have around 60 requests in a month
- The lookup form uses a honeypot and validation to restrict submissions
- The lat/lon for the store finder come from the database. The lookup only occurs when the form is used.
- We have sites running the same sort of lookup on non-cloud hosting working fine.
- The pages with the maps are only being loaded around 1000 times a month.

We're out of ideas - anyone know what else we could try?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that you use a key? What's the IP of the server?

Comment: Definitely using a key... IP is 46.29.93.115

Comment: This IP seems to be in use for 10 domains(or more), not 2 domains(see http://iplist.net/46.29.93.115/ ). But that wouldn't be an issue when you use a key... I have no idea, sorry.